# Mongodb access on Meteor tutorial step 3

Tags: macos, mongodb, meteor, terminal

https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/collections

I'm working through this tutorial on a macbook air. When I run the

> meteor mongo

command, I get

> mongo: Meteor isn't running a local MongoDB server.

when i then try

> sudo meteor mongo simple-todos

I get a password prompt, but when I put in my mac user password i then get prompted for a username and a password. I tried my mac username and password again but this didn't work. Is this a username and password for mongodb? The tutorial doesn't mention anything about this.

UPDATE:
I stopped and restarted meteor, now when i try

> meteor mongo simple-todos

I get

> Couldn't open a mongo connection: Connection error (EACCES, open

and if i try

> sudo meteor mongo simple-todos
>   I get
>   Couldn't open a mongo connection: Connection error (getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND)

Comment: The intention is that your app ( and therefore the launched instance of MongoDB ) is still running when you run these things. Run them in separate terminal windows. Also there is absolutely no need for `sudo` in any of the stages, and you will likely cause harm by changing permissions if you do.

Comment: thanks. the app is running whil i'm running these commands. I've had to use sudo quite a few times when installing meteor, github etc - should i make a change to my user setting? I installed mongodb by itself previously, is this potentially causing a problem?

Comment: That is not what the errors you are reporting are saying. The specific error is because the app is in fact not running at all, **or** that you explicitly asked to use a different MongoDB instance in your application setup, rather than the one meteor spawns by default when you do not. In the latter case, then just connect your mongodb shell as you normally would.

Comment: sorry, i'm new to mongodb. what does ' then just connect your mongodb shell as you normally would.' mean?

Comment: just updated original post after restarting meteor

Comment: could this be happening becuase i installed mongodb separately a few weeks before installing meteor?